# No muestra mi modal boostrap

Tags: html, modal, fullcalendar

Estoy trabajando con FullCalendar, el problema que tengo es el siguiente:

tengo un botón para agregar registros, cuando lo presiono me abre el modal, pero si lo cierro y vuelvo a presionar el botón, ya no me sale el modal deja como una linea en la parte superior.

Anexo imágenes, espero puedan ayudarme.

repo: https://bitbucket.org/arelipca/embarques/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo: 
Boton:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning btnAddUser" onclick="valida_envia()" <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i> Agregar</button>

<script>
function valida_envia(){  
                    $('#newEvent').modal('show');
                }  
</script>

Modal: 


<form id="nuevoEvento" method="post">
    <div id="newEvent" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">       
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo Registro</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"> 
                    <div id="datos_ajax_event"></div>                        
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Datos de Evento</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body"> 
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top: -25px">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-backdrop="false">Cerrar</button>                    
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->         
    </div>          
</form>
```

Comment: podrias poner tu codigo html... !!

Comment: Pon el codigo amigo

Comment: sin codigo nada que podamos hacer gracias!

Comment: Acabo de probar tu codigo y funciona bien

Comment: de pronto seria bueno que pongas todo tu html no solo la parte del modal, quiza el problema esta en la estructura de tu pagina

Comment: @Tegito123 les dejo la liga del repo en el que esta el proyecto 
https://bitbucket.org/arelipca/embarques

al igual en la clase que estoy trabajando es shippE.php,

si quito <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>  funciona el boton

Comment: Puede que tengas mas de un 'div' con el mismo id, ya que el código que posteaste funciona normalmente.

Comment: tratar de limpiar la capcha del navegador ctrl+f5 y prueba otra vez papu

Comment: tambien probe tu codigo y funciona bien pana

Comment: No, ya probe y sigue sin funcionar al segundo click